# Trading View Pine Script How to calculate total cost of entry

Tags: pine-script

I have created a simple strategy with no exit condition:

```
strategy("RSI Check",overlay=true, pyramiding=5000)
rsi3=(rsi(close,3))
if(rsi3<=20)
    strategy.entry("Buy",strategy.long)
```

I want to find the total buy price of all pyramid position , so if buy is trigger 100 times , i want all the 100 entry price sum. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you need 
`strategy.position_size * strategy.position_avg_price`